# How to stub or mock another node module that is required in a function I'm trying to test

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, sinon

I'm trying to test a function that has a reference to a custom node module, that I need to mock / stub, as its not native to node.

The module is called jwt, and I am wanting to mock this and stub the .addOperation and .decode methods, so I can test the if else block.

This is the function.

```
static verifyTokenAndExpiry (jwt, jwk) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      let jwtLib = require('jwt')
      let decoder = new jwtLib.Decoder(jwt)
      decoder.addOperation('verify', jwk)
        .addOperation({ validateDataType: false, validateAudience: false, validateExpiration: true, validateNotBefore: true }, 'validate')
        .decode(function (error, claims) {
          if (error) {
            console.error('Failed to decode token, not a valid encoded format or expired: ', error)
            reject(error)
          } else {
            console.trace('Token was decoded and passed expiry check: ', claims)
            resolve(true)
         }
       })
    })
  }
```

This is the start of the test.

```
describe('CommonLib - verifyTokenAndExpiry', () => {
  it('Should return true', async () => {
    let decoder = {
      addOperation: ''
    }

    mock('jwt', { Decoder: sinon.stub(decoder, 'addOperation').callsFake(function fakeFn () {})

  })
  //  sinon.stub(decoder,"addOperation").callsFake(function fakeFn () {})
    let response = await CommonLib.verifyTokenAndExpiry('', '')
  })

})
```

This is the error I currently get.

TypeError: decoder.addOperation is not a function

If someone could post how the test should be setup that would be great.

Comment: Did you get through it ?

Comment: did you try adding function instead of string :  let decoder = {
      addOperation: function(){}
    }